# Laravel how to handle recurring To-Do Tasks?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm creating a To-Do application where users can create recurring tasks like weekly, monthly etc. An email notification will be sent to the user three weeks before the task is due. So if you create a weekly task with due date tomorrow(let's say the date is 01.01), the application will create three duplicates(08.01, 15.01, 22.01) so that it will cover the email notice date span.
But I can't figure out how to make it automatically create a new task every week after that. I'm using Laravel 5.4.
Any inputs is appreciated!

Comment: have you looked at laravel schedules https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling

Comment: You can create a command that gets run by laravel's task scheduler. Pseudocode: `getAllTasksThatRecur(); addRecurrences(); saveToDatabase()`. The docs are pretty clear on this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling#scheduling-artisan-commands

Comment: Thank you both!
Turns out laravel's scheduler was what I was looking for.